# Usage of AWK in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk

please explain the line below used in shell scripts,

```
awk -F\| -v src=$storekey 'src==$41' $SRC_Path >> $DST_Path
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn basic syntax of AWK. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first `${variable}` is a shell variable, so those would be defined higher in your script i.e.

storekey = "1234" or something

you can try this on your shell (linux or command line terminal)

type:

```
$ storekey="foo"
$ echo $storekey
```

So most of your question is pertaining to the variables and the command line which confuses how they are used, if you replaced the variables on a command line to test, you could work test it out to find out what they are doing.

In essence Awk is a stream parsing tool, so if you had a file of say 10 columns with a known delimiter such as "," or "|" you could ask awk for a specific column to be printed or output. This is what is happening below, but it is being confused by the presence of custom shell variables.

then to break down the command line awk is parsing a "|" delimited input (-F\| ) defined by $storekey variable, taking the column where src== $41 (this has some reference to the data being input), from $SRC_PATH (a directory) to $DST_PATH (another directory or path).

If you could share more of the shell script I could provide a more in depth answer.

btw, you could also find out more information, using the commands

- `man awk`
- `info awk`

from your command line, however these are a bit arcane for those not so familiar with *nix variants.

Comment: Does this mean that awk is getting what is in column 41?

Comment: yes, $41 = column 41. however it's being matched against src== . Not sure if this helps you understand

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am really trying to know why 41 is the number in that line. This has answered my question.

Comment: @smflores07 please be sure to vote for my answer then!